# Unable to update ListView via a non-Activity Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, listview, android-listview

I have two classes : MainActivity and ClientListManager.

CLientListManager sends messages to MainActivity (via a Handler) on receiving which it is expected to update a ListView. However, it does not happen so.

The content of the message is received correctly but the ListView is not updated per se (I tried updating with listView and adapter but neither works).

The app also has an ActionBar. When I click on one particular tab of the ActionBar, the listView which we are talking about here is inflated.

Now, when I click that Tab, only then the listview is updated. I want to update the ListView on some method like myArrayAdapter.add() or myListView.add() (that is,dynamically)

Just for info. , CLM receives messages from another thread, and on receiving message, the handler of CLM creates another message (and attaches some data) and sends it to the mainAcitivty.

I tried to implement a new application where I use a non-Acitvity Thread to update the contents of a listView via a non-Activity Thread --> MainActivity Thread message sending mechanism (I send the data by sending a List) and I was able to do that without error but here it does not happen. Why ?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.webServer;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {


Activity mainAct;
ActionBar actionbar;
String log;
Handler mainHandler;
int toast = 1, dialog = 2, IPMessage = 3, clientActionBar = 4, serverActionBar = 5, displayServerListUpdate = 6, updateClientListFromUpdatingThread = 9;
public static String internaldirectoryName;
Boolean clientStatus = false, serverStatus = false;
ListView serverListView, clientListView;
static int mainServerPort;
final ArrayList serverList = new ArrayList();
final ArrayList clientList = new ArrayList();
String remoteServerIPForClient;
String remoteServerPortForClient;
Handler clientListHandler;
ArrayAdapter serverAdapter;

ArrayAdapter clientsAdapter;
int p = 0;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 * <p/>
 * 1)Sets up the MainHandler extensively used by other threads and classes.
 * <p/>
 * 2) Sets up the actionBar, lists and adapters.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    View clientView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.clients, null);

    serverListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.s_list);
    clientListView = (ListView)clientView.findViewById(R.id.c_log);


    serverAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, serverList);
    ArrayAdapter clientLogAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, clientList);


    serverListView.setAdapter(clientLogAdapter);
    clientListView.setAdapter(serverAdapter);


    ListView online_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.connected_clients);

    serverList.add("one");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        serverList.add(SystemClock.uptimeMillis());


    Resources res = getResources();
    log = res.getString(R.string.log_text);
    setupActionBar();


    mainHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message m) {

            if (m.getData().getInt("POST") == toast) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, m.getData().getString("CONTENT"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (m.getData().getInt("POST") == dialog) {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setMessage(m.getData().getString("CONTENT")).setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }).show();

            } else if (m.getData().getInt("POST") == IPMessage) {

                serverList.add(m.getData().getString("IPAddress"));

            } else if (m.getData().getInt("POST") == clientActionBar) {

                actionbar.setTitle(m.getData().getString("CONTENT"));
                if (m.getData().getBoolean("CONNECTED"))
                    actionbar.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);
                else if (!(m.getData().getBoolean("CONNECTED")))
                    actionbar.setIcon(R.drawable.red);

            } else if (m.getData().getInt("POST") == displayServerListUpdate) {

                String[] temp = m.getData().getStringArray("COMPLETE CLIENT LIST");
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setMessage("Updating display list with " + temp[0]).setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }).show();

                serverList.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
                    serverList.add(temp[i]);


            } else if (m.getData().getInt("POST") == updateClientListFromUpdatingThread) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Received is " +m.getData().getStringArrayList("COMPLETEC").toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                serverAdapter.addAll(m.getData().getStringArrayList("COMPLETEC"));
                serverAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



            }
```

Comment: you can debug and check your handler is really being called or not as if new items are added into the list or not ?

Comment: @DavidArfin Thanks for a reply! handler is being called. checked using toast message but update in the adapter is reflected only after I click the tab on the actionbar